# wide-angle and zoom cameras aren't accessible on iOS Safari / WebKit

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webrtc, agora.io

I'm building a WebRTC browser app. I use Agora Web SDK 4.7.0, but this shouldn't affect the solution.

Agora has [AgoraRTC.getDevices()](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartc.html?platform=Web#getdevices) method which internally relies on `enumerateDevices` (AFAIK) and it works as expected on Android, returning a list of all the cameras on the device, but on an iPhone it only returns a "Front camera" and a "Back camera". Two more back cameras are missing.

It's the same way when you just open any "online webcam test" website on our iPhone, it only lists two cameras to choose from, whereas on Android you'll see all of them.

Is there any way to make them accessible or somehow obtain the `deviceID` of the wide-angle and zoom cameras on an iPhone?

Comment: Sounds like an iOS issue. Apple decides whether or not these devices show up and it's possible it hasn't been addressed I'd send a support email their way. :)

Comment: @Frosgesicht do you know if this is possible in iOS Safari yet?

Answer (score 0):

With the native SDK you can create an AVCaptureSession and pick the camera and send that feed directly to Agora. I expect there is a similar way to create a camera session via web, pick the camera, and send that feed through to Agora.

There is an article about custom video sources in web here, so if you create a camera stream of the wide lens, this will help push it to the agora engine:
https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/custom_video_web?platform=Web